# Regex c# to jquery implementation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have this regex on my asp.net mvc3 application:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,20}$");
```

I needed to implement this with jquery due to some requirements with something like this:

```
password.match(/(.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]/))
```

This is working. It will detect if 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 1 number is present on the password. However , i also have need to detect if 3 consecutive letter is present (eg: aaa, bbb).

With my regex on c# , it is working with the help of:

```
/(.)\1\1/
```

But I can't make it work on `password.match(/(.)\1\1/)`

Did I missed something here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied your C# regex and tried in JavaScript console and it works great:

```
"waweEEad2".match(/^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,20}$/)
```

returns `["waweEEad2", undefined]` and

```
"waweEEEad2".match(/^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,20}$/)
```

returns `null`.